# Missing Android Support Library or Google Repository in my Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-sdk-2.3

Due to Build of an Android Project, I found that my Android SDK doesn't have Android Support Library or Google Play services or their new equivalents Support Library and Google Repository. I'm using Android SDK and Android Studio on the MacOSX.

My SDK screenshot is attached.
[image: My Android SDK Screenshot on macOS]

What's the problem? And How can I install Android Support Library and Google Play Services on my Android SDK?

Comment: Take a look at `Tools->Android->SDK Manager` in Android Studio.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @DigitalNinja, I've done it, and The Screen Shot is its result! But I couldn't find anything regularly there! Take a look at The Screen Shot!

Comment: @gustavogbc, I'm using Android Studio 2.3 which is built on February 24, 2017!